Pandas assign group ID including unambiguous NaNs
Suppose we have a dataframe with several columns, where missing values (NaN) are encoded as empty strings. Given a set of columns, I want to create an ID number such that:

Rule 1: the ID is the same for all rows having identical or NaN values in that column set
Rule 2: the ID is different for rows if any columns in the column set have >= 2 different non-NaN values, even if ignoring those columns, the rows would be assigned the same ID; rule 2 has priority over and overrides rule 1.

Expected output (for example dataframes, ID based on col1-col4):
    col0  col1  col2 col3  col4  ID
0  hello     1                1   0
1   tree     2  test          2   1
2  world     2          3     2   1   # ID identical to row 1: col1 and col4 are identical, col2 and col3 only contain max. one unique non-NaN value
3  apple     3                2   2

     col0  col1  col2 col3  col4  ID
0  hello     1                1   0
1   tree     2  test          2   1   # IDs different for rows 1, 2 and 4 because col3 contains two different non-NaN values for those rows
2  world     2          3     2   2   # IDs different for rows 1, 2 and 4 because col3 contains two different non-NaN values for those rows
3  apple     3                2   3
4    dog     2  test    4     2   4   # IDs different for rows 1, 2 and 4 because col3 contains two different non-NaN values for those rows

     col0  col1  col2 col3  col4  ID
0  hello     1                1   0
1   tree     2  test          2   1   # IDs different for rows 1, 2 and 4 because col3 contains two different non-NaN values for those rows
2  world     2          3     2   2   # IDs different for rows 1, 2 and 4 because col3 contains two different non-NaN values for those rows
3  apple     3                2   3
4    dog     2  test    4     2   4   # IDs different for rows 1, 2 and 4 because col3 contains two different non-NaN values for those rows
5    dog     1  test          1   0   # ID identical to row0: col1 and col4 are identical, col2 and col3 only contain max. one unique non-NaN value **for row0 and row5**

How can an ID as shown in the expected output be assigned to the rows? Can this be achieved via some df.groupby() operation or is it necessary to iteratively check the column values for each row against previously stored value tuples?
Below is a code attempting to create the ID column via df.groupby().ngroup(). However, grouping by the non-NaN columns only works for the first dataframe (since it does not apply rule 2), grouping by all columns only works for the second dataframe (since it does not apply rule 1). The ID numbers are not sorted, but this is not a big issue here.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# example dataframes with empty strings
df_test1 = pd.DataFrame({'col0': ['hello','tree','world','apple'], 'col1': [1,2,2,3], 'col2': ['','test','',''], 'col3': ['','','3',''], 'col4': [1,2,2,2]})
df_test2 = pd.DataFrame({'col0': ['hello','tree','world','apple','dog'], 'col1': [1,2,2,3,2], 'col2': ['','test','','','test'], 'col3': ['','','3','','4'], 'col4': [1,2,2,2,2]})
df_test1 = df_test1.replace('', np.nan)
df_test2 = df_test2.replace('', np.nan)

def id_ngroup(df_in, groupby_cols):
    # create an ID via grouping by columns
    df = df_in.copy()
    df['ID'] = df.groupby(groupby_cols, dropna=False).ngroup()

    return df

df_test1a = id_ngroup(df_test1, groupby_cols=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
df_test2a = id_ngroup(df_test2, groupby_cols=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
print("IDs grouping by all columns:")
print("Test1a:\n",df_test1a)
print("Test2a:\n",df_test2a)

df_test1b = id_ngroup(df_test1, groupby_cols=['col1','col4'])
df_test2b = id_ngroup(df_test2, groupby_cols=['col1','col4'])
print("IDs grouping by non-NaN columns only:")
print("Test1b:\n",df_test1b)
print("Test2b:\n",df_test2b)


Are the missing values only in col2/3? Also if you have something like 1/NaN/3/4 ; 1/2/NaN/4 ; and 1/5/NaN/4, how should the IDs match?

Missing values could occur in any column, i.e. both in columns that we want to use to define the ID as well as in any other columns of the dataframe.
row1 = 1/NaN/3/4; row2 = 1/2/NaN/4; row3 = 1/5/NaN/4
all get different IDs: cols 1 and 4 would match and they would be assigned the same ID; col3 has one unique non-NaN value for those rows, not changing the group ID; however, then col 2 has >= 2 unique non-NaN values for these rows.

OK, then what about 1/2/3/4, 1/NaN/3/4, 1/5/3/4 ? According to Rule1 1/2/3/4 and 1/NaN/3/4 should get the same ID, but also 1/5/3/4 and 1/NaN/3/4, which is incompatible since 1/2/3/4 and 1/5/3/4 cannot have the same id

Cols 1, 3 and 4 match --> all 3 rows in one group; col 2 has >= 2 unique non-NaN values (i.e. 2, 5) --> split the group again and assign 3 distinct IDs.

OK, I'm not sure I get the full logic but it seems to me that an iterative solution might be needed.

Yes, it seems like that to me as well. Basically the logic should be sth. like: (1) Assign an ID based only on the columns without any NaN values. (2): Consider columns that only contain NaNs + 1 unique non-NaN value; this then does not change the assigned IDs. (3): Within each group identified so far, if any column now has >= 2 unique non-NaN values, assign distinct IDs to all group members (of course also different from all other assigned IDs).

@mozway: I think I did not clarify it well in the text (will update), but rule 2 should have priority (i.e. override) rule 1. That should resolve your comment regarding rule incompatibility.
